# 'min' and 'max' functions returning the same values from a .txt file of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

I've created a program that reads a .txt file and appends a list of grades from it. When I try to get the min and max values from that list, it returns the same value even though the list contains a large range of numbers.

The .txt file is formatted like this:

```
name
grade
name
grade
```

Here is my code:

```
def main ():

    #open gradebook
    gradebook_file = open ('gradebook.txt', 'r')
    name = gradebook_file.readline ()
    grade = float (gradebook_file.readline ())
    numbers = []
    for lines in gradebook_file:
        numbers.append (grade)

    _min = min (numbers)
    _max = max (numbers)

    #define variable to read contents of gradebook
    contents = gradebook_file.read ()

    #print contents
    print (contents)
    print ('The minimum average grade was a(n) ' + str (_min) + '.')
    print ('The maximum average grade was a(n) ' + str (_max) + '.')

    #close the gradebook
    gradebook_file.close ()

#call main
main ()
```

Comment: In your surely hour-long debugging session, have you ever tried `print(numbers)`?

Comment: You are reading only 1 grade and 1 name, I am modifying your code now.

Answer (score 3):

```
grade = float (gradebook_file.readline ())
numbers = []
for lines in gradebook_file:
    numbers.append (grade)
```

you convert the second line to float, and iterate on the rest of the file appending the same value all over again.

you get a list with the same values all over, so `min(numbers)`==`max(numbers)` !

Quick fix to read one line out of two (the odd one) and skip the names:

```
numbers = [float(line) for i,line in enumerate(gradebook_file) if i%2]
```

Last note: when you do `contents = gradebook_file.read ()` after having read the file, it reads nothing: you've already exhausted the file generator.

Comment: can someone explain the downvote? if my answer is wrong I'll correct it or delete it (already deleted answers with +3 votes so it's not an issue)

Comment: Stack Overflow has gotten ornery lately. I don't see anything that deserves a downvote.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks. I suspect that someone is considering that the OP should debug by himself, the question is bad, and answerers should be punished. I know that. In those cases, I try to be super-helpful, and go beyond the trivial answer to try to improve OP code instead of quickfixing it with some lousy code.

Comment: This quickfix still fails to return the correct minimum value.

Comment: probably because you didn't remove your code: `name = gradebook_file.readline ()
    grade = float (gradebook_file.readline ())` so first value is skipped. If this was the minimum, then it's not in `numbers`